# windows "C:/Users/<username>/" directories not visible during `docker build` command

Tags: linux, windows, docker

From what I know, `docker-machine` automatically mounts the `C:/Users/<username>` directory in windows. I am able to access it from the quick start terminal as `/c/Users/<username>` and perform all sorts of operations on it.
However when I `RUN` a command from inside `Dockerfile`, docker engine simply doesn't recognize this mounted path.
For instance I have `activator` zip located at:

```
/c/Users/someuser/somefolder/typesafe-activator-1.3.10.zip
```

Previously, I was using `wget`in `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN wget https://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/1.3.10/typesafe-ctivator-1.3.10.zip && unzip typesafe-activator-1.3.10.zip
```

Now since I already have this zip in the file system, I want to:

```
RUN cp /c/Users/someuser/somefolder/typesafe-activator-1.3.10.zip . && unzip typesafe-activator-1.3.10.zip
```

But I get:

```
cp:cannot stat '/c/Users/someuser/somefolder/typesafe-activator-1.3.10.zip': No such file or directory
```

Any one know how I can get a file from the shared folders on the host machine into the docker build process?

**UPDATE**
Here is my complete `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ENV PROJECT_WORKPLACE /usr/src
RUN mkdir -p $PROJECT_WORKPLACE/activator $PROJECT_WORKPLACE/build    $PROJECT_WORKPLACE/app

WORKDIR $PROJECT_WORKPLACE/activator

COPY . typesafe-activator-1.3.10.zip
RUN unzip typesafe-activator-1.3.10 

ENV PATH $PROJECT_WORKPLACE/activator/typesafe-activator-1.3.10/activator-dist-1.3.10/bin:$PATH

COPY . $PROJECT_WORKPLACE/build

WORKDIR $PROJECT_WORKPLACE/build

RUN activator clean stage

RUN cp -R $PROJECT_WORKPLACE/build/target/universal/stage $PROJECT_WORKPLACE/app

EXPOSE 9000

CMD $PROJECT_WORKPLACE/app/stage/bin/docker-play -Dhttp.port=9000 -Dlogger.file=$PROJECT_WORKPLACE/build/logger.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RUN sees the **[Dockerfile context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/usage)**:

The context is the current folder (where the Dockerfile is) and its subfolder.

> The docker build command builds an image from a Dockerfile and a context.
>   The build’s context is the files at a specified location PATH or URL.
>   The PATH is a directory on your local filesystem.
>   The URL is a the location of a Git repository.
>
> A context is processed recursively. So, a PATH includes any subdirectories and the URL includes the repository and its submodules.

Therefore, You don't need to specify the all path.

```
RUN cp typesafe-activator-1.3.10.zip . && unzip typesafe-activator-1.3.10.zip
```

Note: you should use [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/copy) or [`ADD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/add) instead of `RUN cp`

```
COPY typesafe-activator-1.3.10.zip .
RUN unzip typesafe-activator-1.3.10.zip
```

In any case, any resource you need should be in the same folder or subfolder of your Dockerfile.

The [OP egima](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3067615/egima) made it work with:

```
ADD typesafe-activator-1.3.10.zip .
```

Comment: that was the perfect tweak I needed for including resources though I had to add a period after `COPY`. However, new issues are up. I have added the complete `Dockerfile`. At the `unzip` step, I get `unzip: cannot find or open typesafe-activator-1.3.10, typesafe-activator-1.3.10.zip or typesafe-activator-1.3.10.ZIP`

Comment: @egima try adding, after the `COPY`, a `RUN pwd`, and `RUN ls` to get a sense of where you did the copy.

Comment: Tried, for some reason, replacing `COPY` with `ADD` and swapping the positions of period (src) with filename(destination) worked. thanks

Comment: @egima Great: what exact command did you use then? `ADD typesafe-activator-1.3.10.zip .` ?

Comment: sure, that's the exact one I used

Comment: @egima Great. I have included it to the answer for more visibility, and for others to benefit from.

Comment: can you checkout [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636072/sbt-failed-download-in-running-play-docker-container) too