# sbt failed download in running play docker container

Tags: windows, maven, docker, playframework, sbt

I have successfully built my docker image for a `play-java`. But while trying to spawn a container for it with `docker run -p 0.0.0.0:9000:9000 egima/play activator run` sbt fails to download one particular dependency. The log looks like this:

```
==== Maven2 Local: tried
  file:/root/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/3.1.0/sisu-guice-3.1.0.jar
==== Apache Repository: tried  https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/3.1.0/sisu-guice-3.1.0.jar[0m
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
    :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    :: org.sonatype.sisu#sisu-guice;3.1.0!sisu-guice.jar
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Notice the the `tried` repositories. I have followed [all the different variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773319/sbt-doesnt-find-file-in-local-maven-repository-although-its-there) for including the `local` maven repos on my machine, I confirm from the logs that sbt checks according to what I have specified in the local maven repos but no luck.
My resolvers in both `build.sbt` and `/project/plugins.sbt`:

```
resolvers ++=Seq(
    Resolver.sonatypeRepo("public"),
    Resolver.mavenLocal,
    "Apache Repository" at "https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/"
    )
```

I also checked my local maven repo to ensure the missing dependency exists. What is missing?

Comment: /root/.m2? Why using the root account?

Comment: @VonC, that path is automatically converted by `sbt` from `Resolver.mavenLocal`. I also tried the paths that worked for others in the linked question, still no luck.

Comment: Sure: it resolves to $HOME/.m2. Is that folder empty? Shouldn't it contain some elements? Do you have a local .m2 folder that you should share (-v)?

Comment: In windows, I have `C:\Users\me\.m2\repository`, not sure if  by `/root/.m2` sbt means `C:\Users\me\.m2`. But the host path I have given is very valid and stores all my maven artifacts.

Comment: Try, in your dockerfile a `RUN ln -s /C/Users/me/.m2 /root/.m2`: rebuild the image and relaunch the container.

Comment: @VonC. This command exposed other findings which I have documented in a complete answer, let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) suggested in the comments section to add the following step in `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN ln -s /C/Users/me/.m2 /root/.m2
```

I believe this command should establish a soft link  between `$MAVEN_HOME` on my host machine and the resolution path `Resolver.mavenLocal` which resolves to `/root/.m2`. 
This should be the solution. However, after trying it, I realized that the shared path `/c/Users/me`(invisible with capital C, don't know why) is visible inside the VM but invisible inside a container. So including that line inside `Dockerfile` would give me:

```
ln:cannot access /c/Users/me/.m2: No such file or directory
```

Additionally, even performing `RUN ls /root` would give me a similar error meaning the destination path too does not yet exist at this time.
My own deduction is that the solution lies in mounting the host path onto the destination path by any method available which I think is a well discussed topic on this forum. For my particular situation **performing a mount** during `docker run` with the `-v` flag solved the problem.
This is the exact command I used:

```
docker run -v /c/Users/me/.m2:/root/.m2 -p 0.0.0.0:9000:9000 egima/play activator run
```

I have written [a complete blog post](http://www.egimaben.com/sbt-fails-to-see-local-maven-repository/) about his for those that need more information.