# Docker Windows 7: Could not find matching IP for MAC address error

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

I have been running Docker on my windows with Docker ToolBox all fine for last 6 months. Suddenly, when starting my docker console I started getting following error:

`Error creating machine: Error running provisioning: Could not find matching IP for MAC address 0800270a0700`

I came across many threads on GitHub and SO and most of the people suggested completely removing Docker setup including Virtual Box and re-installing it. Which I did however I am getting the same error even on a clean set up.

I tried following things so far:

- Clean re-install of docker and Virtual Box
- Making sure that all the docker related folders that I find are removed before the next install(Removed both `.docker` and `.virtualbox` folders)
- also removed default docker-machine on existing set up after the new installation failed by doing `docker-machine rm default`

Also, one thing to notice that when I do a clean install, I can see that when I fire up the docker quickstart for the first time it starts everything from the scratch except one thing. I see this message that it

`Found a new host-only adapter: "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter#2`

Which raises the questions that if if **found** it then it must not be new right? and also why is it #2? why not #1 or no number? The reason I am bringing this up is because I am suspecting that when a `clean-install` happens, it is really not clean, I think it is getting some screwed up settings from somewhere and that somewhere can very well be this network adapter

If I look at the logs inside the Docker-machine then logs look like following. Now sure if that is any help

`00:00:48.657014 VMMDev: Guest Log: 00:00:00.009234 vminfo   rtldrNativeLoad: dlopen('libdbus-1.so.3', RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL) failed: libdbus-1.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
00:00:48.657044 VMMDev: Guest Log: 00:00:00.009268 vminfo   Error: Unable to connect to system D-Bus (1/3): D-Bus not installed
00:00:48.659892 VMMDev: Guest Additions capability report: (0x0 -> 0x0) seamless: no, hostWindowMapping: no, graphics: no
00:00:48.805170 NAT: IPv6 not supported
00:00:50.624628 NAT: DHCP offered IP address 10.0.2.15
00:00:50.624913 NAT: DHCP offered IP address 10.0.2.15
00:00:53.656655 VMMDev: Guest Log: 00:00:05.010825 vminfo   Error: Unable to connect to system D-Bus (2/3): D-Bus not installed
00:00:58.658074 VMMDev: Guest Log: 00:00:10.012264 vminfo   Error: Unable to connect to system D-Bus (3/3): D-Bus not installed
00:01:00.230853 VMMDev: SetVideoModeHint: Got a video mode hint (800x600x0)@(0x0),(1;0) at 0
00:01:44.873806 Changing the VM state from 'RUNNING' to 'SUSPENDING'
00:01:45.187049 PDMR3Suspend: 313 213 266 ns run time
00:01:45.187066 Changing the VM state from 'SUSPENDING' to 'SUSPENDED'
00:01:45.187073 Console: Machine state changed to 'Paused'
00:01:48.209792 Changing the VM state from 'SUSPENDED' to 'RESUMING'
00:01:48.247728 Changing the VM state from 'RESUMING' to 'RUNNING'
00:01:48.247754 Console: Machine state changed to 'Running'
00:06:42.762538 Changing the VM state from 'RUNNING' to 'SUSPENDING'
00:06:42.958664 PDMR3Suspend: 196 100 930 ns run time
00:06:42.958705 Changing the VM state from 'SUSPENDING' to 'SUSPENDED'
00:06:42.958714 Console: Machine state changed to 'Paused'`

I have had no luck so far.  Any help?

Comment: Have you checked this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783979/docker-machine-error-could-not-find-matching-ip-for-mac-address-on-windows-10

Comment: @Rao yup I did and followed the instructions but no luck

Comment: Are you manually able to start the machine in VM and do you see any errors inside it?

Comment: @TarunLalwani, the `docker-machine` does not show any error but I pulled up the logs for docker machine and seems like they had some errors. I updated my question details with those logs. Hope that helps

Comment: Are you using a VPN like Citrix? If so, disconnect it and then try to create the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a VPN like Citrix? If so, disconnect it and then try to create the machine.