# Cant install minishift with Virtualbox on Windows 10

Tags: virtualbox, minishift

I am trying to install minishift on my Windows 10 Enterprise laptop.
The commands I execute in powershell are:

```
minishfit config set vm-driver hyperv
minishift start
```

The trace is:

```
-- Starting profile 'minishift'
-- Check if deprecated options are used ... OK
-- Checking if https://github.com is reachable ... OK
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.11.0' is valid ... OK
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.11.0' is supported ... OK
-- Checking if requested hypervisor 'virtualbox' is supported on this platform ... OK
-- Checking if VirtualBox is installed ... OK
-- Checking the ISO URL ... OK
-- Checking if provided oc flags are supported ... OK
-- Starting the OpenShift cluster using 'virtualbox' hypervisor ...
-- Starting Minishift VM ............................ FAIL E0130 16:57:39.360592    1632 start.go:494] Error starting the VM: Error configuring authorization on host: Could not find matching IP for MAC address XXXXXXX. Retrying.
Error starting the VM: Error configuring authorization on host: Could not find matching IP for MAC address XXXXXXX
```

Can anyone please help resolve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Did you search stackoverflow? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783979/docker-machine-error-could-not-find-matching-ip-for-mac-address-on-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

So you first set "hyperv" as vm-driver for Minishift, but then when the machine starts the Minishift reports to use "virtualbox"? This seems suspicious and could be the reason for problems.

If your plan is to use virtualbox, then set it as vm-driver in Minishift and make sure that Hyper-V functionality is disabled on the machine (needs restart to disable).

If your plan is to start Minishift with Hyper-V (and you have also VB installed on the machine), then run "minishift config view" to see whether hyperv was really set up as vm-driver - strangely the Minishift start reports as if hyperv was not set. Make sure Hyper-V is enabled (needs restart to enable). Start minishift and check that it reports hyperv to be used:

```
-- Starting the OpenShift cluster using 'hyperv' hypervisor ...
```