# How to specify the IP address when creating a docker virtual machine

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, virtualbox, docker-machine

I'm trying to create a docker virtual machine and specifying its IP address. This is the command I am using

`docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-hostonly-cidr "192.168.99.110/24" --virtualbox-memory 4096 devmachine`

However, it still assigns an IP address incremented by 1. For instance, if I have a `default` virtual machine with an IP address of `192.168.99.100`, the machine that I created will be assigned an IP address of `192.168.99.101`.

How to specify the IP address when creating a docker virtual machine?

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34336218/is-there-a-way-to-force-docker-machine-to-create-vm-with-a-specific-ip

Comment: @JesusRT I have been to that page. The workaround they suggest is using `--virtualbox-hostonly-cidr` which I did. And it does not work :)

Comment: Well looks like is not possible. Why you need to specify an ip address? Maybe your issue can be resolved in other way

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez I need to have the IP address of the docker machine before creating it. It gives me more control in terms of storing configuration - In contrast to waiting for an IP provided by docker