# Docker ip of "default" machine

Tags: docker

I have a few quick, maybe stupid question about docker, when you start it you get the ip of the default machine what is 192.168.99.100 the first time you install it. 
But I removed it and installed it again and now its 192.168.99.101. 
What happend to the first ip and can I change the 192.168.99.101 to 192.168.99.100 again?
I used the docker-toolbox to install docker!
Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34336218/is-there-a-way-to-force-docker-machine-to-create-vm-with-a-specific-ip

Comment: Are you trying to run Docker on Mac or Windows?