# How can I run the command to force docker-machine to create a vm with specific address in Windows 10 Home?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I've been following this question to force docker-machine to create a vm with specific address [Is there a way to force docker-machine to create vm with a specific ip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34336218/is-there-a-way-to-force-docker-machine-to-create-vm-with-a-specific-ip)  because I need the docker-machine to work on 192.168.99.100. It seems to work for everybody, but not for me and I think it could be helpful to solve it for Windows Home

I'm using:

```
Windows 10 Home build
Virtual Box Versión 5.2.8 r121009 (Qt5.6.2)
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:       18.03.0-ce
 API version:   1.37
 Go version:    go1.9.4
 Git commit:    0520e24302
 Built: Fri Mar 23 08:31:36 2018
 OS/Arch:       windows/amd64
 Experimental:  false
 Orchestrator:  swarm
error during connect: Get https://192.168.99.101:2376/v1.37/version: dial tcp 192.168.99.101:2376: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

```
usuario@DESKTOP-GTCQCAR MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox
$ echo "ifconfig eth0 192.168.99.100 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.99.255 up" | docker-machine ssh default su
do tee /var/lib/boot2docker/bootsync.sh > /dev/null
tee: C:/Program: No such file or directory
tee: Files/Git/var/lib/boot2docker/bootsync.sh: No such file or directory
exit status 1
```

The second part of the command does not work:

docker-machine ssh default sudo tee /var/lib/boot2docker/bootsync.sh > /dev/null

The script does not work either:  C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox>dmvbf default 99 100

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set machine=%1
if "%machine%" == "" (
    echo dmvbf expects a machine name
    exit /b 1
)
set ipx=%2
if "%ipx%" == "" (
    echo dmvbf x missing ^(for 192.168.x.y^)
    exit /b 2
)
set ipy=%3
if "%ipy%" == "" (
    echo dmvbf y missing ^(for 192.168.x.y^)
    exit /b 3
)

echo kill $(more /var/run/udhcpc.eth0.pid) | docker-machine ssh %machine% sudo tee /var/lib/boot2docker/bootsync.sh >NUL
echo ifconfig eth0 192.168.%ipx%.%ipy% netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.%ipx%.255 up | docker-machine ssh %machine% sudo tee -a /var/lib/boot2docker/bootsync.sh >NUL
echo route add default gw <gateway ip address here> | docker-machine ssh %machine% sudo tee /bar/lib/boot2docker/bootsync.sh >NUL

docker-machine ssh %machine% "sudo cat /var/run/udhcpc.eth0.pid | xargs sudo kill"

docker-machine ssh %machine% "sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.%ipx%.%ipy% netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.%ipx%.255 up"
```

saying that

```
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox>dmvbf default 99 100
Error: Cannot run SSH command: Host "default" is not running
Error: Cannot run SSH command: Host "default" is not running
Not expected | at this momment.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error you are facing seems self-explanatory: the machine "default" does not seem to exist or is not running.

First of all, make sure the machine exists by typing the following in an elevated powershell:

```
 docker-machine ls
```

If you see the machine, make sure it is running by typing the following:

```
docker-machine start MyMachineName
```

Otherwise, create a new one:

```
docker-machine create MyMachineName
```

Another reason why it could fail is not having set the right virtual switch when creating your docker-machine.

Hope this helps